# mysql not showing error if parent id is missing in child table for foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

I have created 2 tables  employees as parent table and departments as child table and in departments table employee_id is foreign key created, but if I try to insert data first in child table without inserting record in parent table then data get inserted successfully, however I want some error should be appear because without parent table id record we should insert child data as here we have maintain reference foreign key constraints

Mysql queries:

parent table

```
CREATE TABLE employees
( employee_id numeric (20) not null,
employee_name varchar(75) not null,
supervisor_name varchar(75),
CONSTRAINT employee_pk PRIMARY KEY (employee_id)
);
```

Child table

```
CREATE TABLE departments
( department_id numeric (20) not null,
employee_id numeric (20) not null,
CONSTRAINT fk_employee
FOREIGN KEY (employee_id)
REFERENCES employee (employee_id)
);
```

Comment: Are these MyISAM tables? MyISAM does not support or enforce foreign key constraints. You must use InnoDB.

Comment: @Bill Karwin  I am using InnoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the name itself.The name of the table is **employees**
Whereas in the references  part it is placed as **employee**. Here also it needs to be employees.

```
CREATE TABLE departments
( department_id numeric (20) not null,
employee_id numeric (20) not null,
CONSTRAINT fk_employee
FOREIGN KEY (employee_id)
REFERENCES employees (employee_id)
);
```

Comment: thanks, can u please tell me how to see this created constarin name using query